# Python DateTime if statement behaves different in Azure.(Django WebApp)

Tags: python, json, django, azure, python-datetime

So i'm writing a little Django webApp. It uses JSON data from a API to render everything. In localhost, everything runs fine. But in Azure it does not.


The is somewhere in this code:

```
for appointment in appointmentsMaandag:
    starttijd = (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(appointment['start'])).strftime('%H%M')
    SuMa = 0
    if  800 <= int(starttijd) < 850:
        SuMa = 0
    elif  850 <= int(starttijd) < 940:
        SuMa = 1
    elif  940 <= int(starttijd) < 1050:
        SuMa = 2
    elif  1050 <= int(starttijd) < 1140:
        SuMa = 3
    elif  1140 <= int(starttijd) < 1240:
        SuMa = 4
    elif  1240 <= int(starttijd) < 1350:
        SuMa = 5
    elif  1350 <= int(starttijd) < 1440:
        SuMa = 6
    elif  1440 <= int(starttijd) < 1530:
        SuMa = 7
    else:
        SuMa = 8
    break
```

In azure, this always outputs the `ELSE`. `SuMa = 8` in this case. In Localhost it does work. Since I have no experience whatsoever with azure, I was wondering if any of you could help me.


I use VS 2015 with Python Tools.

Comment: Check that your timezone is the same on localhost and azure.

Comment: This shouldn't matter, since it gets the date from JSON and it doesn't use datetime.datetime.now().

Comment: I guess it did matter ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a timezone issue. As when we need to parse timestamp to datetime object, it will need the timezone setting, and by default it will leverage the system timezone. And the timezone on Azure services are all the same as **America/Los_Angeles**.

So you need to set your local timezone in your code, E.G:

```
import pytz
localtz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Hong_Kong')
starttijd = (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(appointment['start'],tz=localtz)).strftime('%H%M')
print starttijd
```

...